# Eclipse's XML Editor Includes ns: Prefix

Tags: xml, eclipse, xml-namespaces

I am using eclipse's XML editor to edit a DocBook file.

I don't want the `<ns:`, I just want `<callout`.

How to prevent this?

[image]

Did some searches, but eclipse's documentation is really poor.

Comment: Care to pastebin the whole file?  The editor doesn't make up prefixes on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the file had the schema listed twice, once with a namespace prefix. Removed the second one, works now.

```
<book xmlns="http://www.manning.com/schemas/book" xmlns:ns="http://www.manning.com/schemas/book"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Thanks.